# "you are being redirected" status code 302 rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, get, httpi

I have an API which when returns me text/css which is in string format instead of JSON, so when I hit that API using Postman I get back the whole css data with status code 200 but when I hit the same API using HTTPI or any other library I am getting status code 302 with "You are being redirected" with redirected being a hyperlink which points to the correct css data.

Here is how I am using HTTPI to make the get request :

```
url = "https://<some-end-point>"
request = HTTPI::Request.new
request.url = url
request.headers = {"Content-Type"=>"text/css","Authorization"=>"
<authorised token>","api_version"=>"1"}
response = HTTPI.get(request)
puts response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of effort, I found out that redirection wasn't supported with HTTPI. So to resolve it I used

> open-uri

which even handles redirection.

```
require 'open-uri'

url = "https://<some-end-point>"
headers = {"Content-Type"=>"text/css","Authorization"=>"<authorised token>","api_version"=>"1"}
buffer = open(url,header).read
```